# Powerpoint to create slideshow to accompany prerecorded audio file?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-powerpoint-2010, slideshow

Can I use Powerpoint to create a slideshow to accompany a prerecorded audio file? This is a bit backwards from the usual situation. Usually, one would prepare the Powerpoint slides, and then record a narration to go with them. The narration segments would be tied to the slides and any animation that might have been set up. Can one work in the other direction? If so, what is the basic procedure, or can you supply a reference?

My audio is a bit over six minutes long.

Comment: 1-> you set up the duration between each slide accordingly to the duration of your recording with: Transitions(tab)->Advance slide->after ...

2-> insert your audio with insert(tab)->audio->(browse your audio)

3-> you have to decide how you plan to start it: on click, on slide etc..

Done

Comment: @Jonathan Thank you very much.  Can I save this or export this to some format that can be uploaded to Youtube or Vimeo?  I want to embed it in a webpage and allow the visitor to click once and then the presentation starts.

Comment: file->save & send-> create a video

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed the step by step instructions at https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/39438/14234.  I found out that Powerpoint had the advantages that (a) I was already familiar with it, and (b) I was able to fill and format the slides with good control.  However, monkeying with the timing was rather tedious.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you completely prepare the visuals then on the opening slide insert the audio file with "on click" as the trigger. Set the audio to play over all slides.

Now rehearse the slide show as many times as needed. Mistakes will mean starting again from the begining!

When you are happy keep the presentaton.

Comment: "On click" does not work as well as "Play across slides."